# How to model demographics

Tags: distributions, poisson-distribution, demography

I tried assuming the number of children a woman has is a Poisson distribution. So, for the US where the mean number of children per woman is currently 1.87, it yields a probability mass function like this:

0: 0.15412386
1: 0.28821161
2: 0.26947786
3: 0.16797453
4: 0.07852809
5: 0.02936951
6: 0.00915350
7: 0.00244529
8: 0.00057159
9: 0.00011876
10: 0.00002221
11: 0.00000378
12: 0.00000059
13: 0.00000008
14: 0.00000001
15: 0.00000000

This does not seem right though because I think the percentage of women who have no children at all is a lot higher than 15% and the number with 15 children is probably more than 1 out of 100 million.

How do I figure out the correct probability mass function?

Comment: "I think" is not a good sign. You should find out more or less accurately what the percentage is before drawing any conclusion. EDIT: A quick google search shows poission estimates are not far off: http://www.pewsocialtrends.org/files/legacy/758-1.png

Comment: Look at this document: https://www.census.gov/content/dam/Census/library/publications/2014/demo/p20-575.pdf You can find the data for 2012. It seems that 41.3% of women aged 15-50 had no children, 17.2% had 1 child, 23.1% had two children and 18.5% had 3 or more children. So, try to find real data and start from there.

Comment: Also, this paper contains several demographic models. It might be helpful: http://www.un.org/esa/population/techcoop/DemEst/manual10/chapter1.pdf

Comment: There's no reason to think that any simple distribution will accurately describe the 'true' population distribution. A simple model may be adequate for some purpose and in other situations you may not need an explicit model at all.  What do you want to do with it?

Comment: @Glen_b Okay, that is interesting, there might be no matching standard  distribution at all, huh? So, in that case I just populate the mass function as I see fit according to what data I have into custom bins, interpolating any unknown values?

Comment: No distribution is likely to exactly describe it (that's true of almost all real data). Some distributions may produce an adequate fit for some purpose. Or you might be able to get a good approximation using mixture distributions - it depends on what you're trying to achieve and why. Just because commonly used distributions don't necessarily fit well enough for whatever you're doing doesn't automatically mean you can't find an adequate approximation. But yes, in many cases the empirical distribution itself - or some smoothed version of it might be quite usable in many cases.

Answer (score 0):

In the [census document](http://census.gov/content/dam/Census/library/publications/2014/demo/%E2%80%A6) that @milos linked to we see:

> Of all women aged 15 to 50, 17.2 percent had one child, 23.1 percent
>   had two children, and 18.5 percent had three or more children.

and therefore 41.2% had no children.

In your Poisson estimate the numbers are indeed quite different. That estimate has far too few with 0 children and too many with 3 or more. So, Poisson doesn't fit well.

If you want to model the real data with some theoretical distribution, you could try a zero inflated Poisson or perhaps a zero inflated negative binomial. [This thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189005/simulate-from-a-zero-inflated-poisson-distribution) shows how to do this. You may have to play a bit with the parameters.