# Generate values from a zero inflated negative binomial fit

Tags: r, zero-inflation

I am using the `pscl` package to fit a simple `zeroinf(...,dist = "negbin")`. I would like to simulate the probability distribution from this fit.

Using another post on cross validated ([Simulate from a zero-inflated poisson distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189005/simulate-from-a-zero-inflated-poisson-distribution)) I see the following for the *poisson* case, but I am not sure what to do for the *negative binomial case*

```
library("VGAM")
library("pscl")
object <- zeroinf(...)
p <- predict(object, ..., type = "zero")
lambda <- predict(object, ..., type = "count")
rzipois(n, lambda = lambda, pstr0 = p)
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, it is simple to generate any zero-inflated pseudo-random variable so long as you can already generate from the corresponding non-zero-inflated version.  Suppose you want to generate $n$ independent values from the zero-inflated version of a random varible $Y \sim F$ with zero-inflation probability $\theta$.  You can generate the pseudo-random variables $X_1,...,X_n \sim \text{IID ZI}_\theta F$ from the corresponding zero-inflated distribution as follows:

- Generate $Y_1,...,Y_n \sim \text{IID } F$.
- Generate $U_1,...,U_n \sim \text{IID Bern}(1-\theta)$.
- Set the values $X_1,...,X_n$ by $X_i = U_i \cdot Y_i$.

You can program this procedure in `R` using the underlying function `rpois` used for generating pseudo-random variables from the Poisson distribution.

```
rzipois <- function (n, lambda, zi.prob) {
  Y <- rpois(n, lambda)
  U <- sample(c(0, 1), size = n, prob = c(zi.prob, 1-zi.prob), replace = TRUE)
  U*Y }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the manual approach from [Simulate from a zero-inflated poisson distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189005/simulate-from-a-zero-inflated-poisson-distribution) and replace the `rpois()` call inside the `ifelse()` by an `rnbinom()` call.

We have also included a somewhat streamlined version of that code as `rzinbinom()` in the [countreg](https://R-Forge.R-project.org/R/?group_id=522) package on R-Forge.